# im grtting an error called (send_login_otp failure - module 'requests' has no attribute 'post4')

Tags: python

first i taut i have multiple file usig same name but i anable to find the file so,  i tried using create new virtual env but i got same error .even i tried to upgrade the package but noting works .
here is my code
import requests

```
 def verify_totp(request_key, totp):

     try:

payload = {

  "request_key": request_key,

  "otp": totp

}



result_string = requests.post4(url=URL_VERIFY_TOTP, json=payload)

if result_string.status_code != 200:

  return [ERROR, result_string.text]



result = json.loads(result_string.text)

request_key = result["request_key"]



return [SUCCESS, request_key]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `requests.post` not `requests.post4`

Also check your `try` block and indentation.

```py
 def verify_totp(request_key, totp):
    # you can avoid the use of a `try except`block if you don't use it

    payload = {

        "request_key": request_key,
        "otp": totp
    }

    result_string = requests.post(url=URL_VERIFY_TOTP, json=payload)

    if result_string.status_code != 200:
        return ["ERROR", result_string.text]

    result = json.loads(result_string.text)
    request_key = result["request_key"]
    
    return ["SUCCESS", request_key]


request_key = "<INSERT YOUR REQUEST KEY HERE>"
totp = "<INSERT YOUR TOTP HERE>"

request_status, request_key = verify_totp(request_key, totp)

print(request_status, request_key)
```

Comment: i tried but now i dont get any output

Comment: @AdityaKoli edited message so that you can see the results. edit the `request_key` and `totp`variables accordingly